# How to find such $\alpha$ and$z$ for holomorphic function that $f(z)=\alpha z^mg(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis

$D=\{z\in \mathbb{C}\mid \lvert z\rvert < 1\}$ $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ holomolphic on $D$ continuous
on $\bar{D}\\$ $|f(z)|\leq|g(z)|(z\in D),$$|f(z)|=|g(z)|(z\in \partial D) ,f(z)\neq0 (z\in\bar{D} \setminus \{0\})$

Then there exits $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$ and integer $m \geq0 $ that$f(z)=\alpha z^mg(z)$

I have tried with maximum principle and Schwarz lemma for $\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ but it requires $g(z) \neq 0$ when $z=0$. Any helpful hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $f$ doesn't vanish except (possibly) at $0$, the same is true of $g$. From $\lvert f(z)\rvert \leqslant \lvert g(z)\rvert$ it follows that $0$ is a removable singularity of $f/g$. Considering it removed, $h = f/g$ is a function that is holomorphic on $D$, continuous on $\overline{D}$, and satisfies $\lvert h(z)\rvert = 1$ on $\partial D$. Furthermore, $h(z) \neq 0$ for $z \neq 0$. If $h$ has a zero of multiplicity $m$ at $0$, then

$$j \colon z \mapsto \frac{h(z)}{z^m}$$

is holomorphic on $D$ (after removing the removable singularity at $0$), continuous on $\bar{D}$, *has no zero in* $D$, and satisfies $\lvert j(z)\rvert = 1$ on $\partial D$. By the minimum modulus principle, $j$ is constant. Let $\alpha$ be its value.

Comment: What if I take $j(z)=z$ we do have $|j(z)|=1$ on $\partial\Bbb D$ as well but j is not constant

Comment: @GuyFsone $j(z) = z$ has a zero in the open unit disk. But $j(z) = \frac{h(z)}{z^m}$ hasn't, by definition of $m$.

Comment: Ok !!! now 
 
What is the problem if the function is constant on the boundary?

Comment: If the function is constant on the boundary, it is constant by the identity theorem. If the modulus of the function is constant on the boundary, _and the function has no zeros in the domain_, then the maximum and minimum modulus principles tell us that the modulus is constant on the domain. And that in turn tells us that the function is constant (since it's holomorphic).

Comment: Sorry I am not an expert in complex analysis. That version of maximum principle with constant modulus on the boundary where can I fine it?

Comment: Don't know where it's stated exactly in that way. But apply the maximum modulus principle to $j$ and to $1/j$ [here we use that $j$ has no zero] to conclude that $\lvert j\rvert$ must be constant [by max-mod, we have $\lvert j(z)\rvert \leqslant c$ and $\lvert 1/j(z)\rvert \leqslant 1/c$ for $z \in D$, where $c$ is the value of $\lvert j\rvert$ on the boundary].

Comment: Here is the [version I know ][https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle  ]. but it does not mention constance modulus on boundary. It is also called modulus principle

Comment: "If $G\subset \mathbb{C}$ is a bounded domain, $f$ holomorphic on $G$ and continuous on $\overline{G}$, then $\lvert f\rvert$ attains its maximum on the boundary of $G$." Equivalent formulations, you can find as Theorem 12' in chapter 4, section 3 of Ahlfors' _Complex Analysis_, corollary 5.7 in chapter 2 of _A Course in Complex Analysis_ by Fischer and Lieb, and a version for the special case of a disk as theorem 10.24 in Rudin's _Real and Complex Analysis_. And of course in many other books on complex analysis.

Comment: This formula is ok I know this : If $G\subset \Bbb C $is a bounded domain, f holomorphic on G and continuous on $\bar{G}$ , then |f| attains its maximum on the boundary of G. But it is does not mention the fact that $|f(z)|$ is constant on the boundary of the G then $f$ is constant:(

Comment: I've explained above how that follows.

Comment: @GuyFsone By the maximum modulus principle, $j$ takes its maximum modulus on the boundary. By the minimum modulus principle (which is just the maximum modulus principle applied to $1/j$, which requires no zeros), $j$ also takes its minimum modulus on the boundary. If the modulus is constant on the boundary, then the minimum modulus and the maximum modulus are equal. Hence the modulus is constant within the interior. And finally if $|j|$ is constant then the image of $j$ lies inside a circle $\{e^{i\theta}|j|\}$ which is not open, so $j$ must be constant by the open mapping theorem.

Comment: @ziggurism thanks for expalantion I got it already